# How can I compile multiple Angular 2 Modules with the angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to compile multiple application nodes using Angular CLI at this time?

When trying to run "ng build -w" it finds the first "app" in the "apps" node of the "angular-cli.json" file.

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist/backoffice",
  "assets": "assets",
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "mobile": false,
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
},
{
  "root": "someOtherApp",
  "outDir": "dist/someOtherApp",
  "assets": "assets",
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "someOtherApp.ts",
  "test": "someOtherApp.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "mobile": false,
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}
```

]

Shouldn't the 2nd application "someOtherApp" start to be compile right afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng build --app=<id>` or `ng build --app=<name>` as stated in the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/multiple-apps.md